# Angular 8 - Delay between value change and template rendering on initial loading

Tags: html, angular

I'm building a classic application that loads data from an http call on its home page. A loader is shown while the data is fetched.

I am experiencing an unusually long loading time of the first http call when the application is initialized. After that, it is very fast, even after refreshing the page.

I noticed in the network inspector that the call is actually finished long time before the loader disappears. After putting some `console.log` here and there, the data is fetched and ready to use, the loader is set to false but it's still showing.

**The component**

```
this.villageService.getVillages().subscribe({
    next: (villages: Village[]) => {
        this.villages = villages.map(village => new Village().fromJson(village));
        this.isLoading = false;
        console.log(this.villages);
        console.log(this.isLoading);
    },
    error: (error: any) => {
        this.isLoading = false;
    },
    complete: () => (this.isLoading = false)
});
```

**The template**

```
<div class="row">
    <app-village-card
        *ngFor="let village of villages | orderByProperty: 'title'"
        class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4"
        [village]="village"
    >
    </app-village-card>
</div>
<app-loader [isLoading]="isLoading" mode="spinner">Loading...</app-loader>
```

The two `console.log` shows the value long before the loader fades away.

So, my conclusion is that, somehow, the rendering of the template is done with a delay, but only when the application is first initialized in the browser.

Comment: This is probably related to the change detection. Do you have `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` on your `@Component`?

Comment: I'm not using changeDetection

Comment: But, you gave me an idea. I've add `this.changeDetector.detectChanges();` and it did the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by forcing a change detection.

```
constructor(
    private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef
) {}

getVillages() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.subscriptions.add(
        this.villageService.getVillages().subscribe({
            next: (villages: Village[]) => {
                this.villages = villages.map(village => new Village().fromJson(village));
                this.isLoading = false;
                this.changeDetector.detectChanges(); // -------> this line
            },
            error: (error: any) => {
                this.isLoading = false;
            },
            complete: () => (this.isLoading = false)
        })
    );
}
```